# AppWidget Parent Layout is larger than it needs to be

Tags: android, android-widget

For some reason my app widget's parent is way larger than it should be.  This is causing the user to be unable to move an icon up against the widget the way they should be able to.

I want it to be 450x352 but the AppWdigetHostView is 608x390 and the parent Linear Layout is 584x366.

[image]

widget_large_info.xml

```
<appwidget-provider xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:minWidth="294dp"
android:minHeight="72dp"
android:updatePeriodMillis="86400000"
android:initialLayout="@layout/widget_layout_large" />
```

widget_layout_large.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_margin="0dip"
    android:background="#FF0000" >

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="450dip"
    android:layout_height="352dip" >

    <!-- sub widgets and views -->

</RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Has anyone seen anything like this?  No matter what I do to the width's and height's it doesn't want to size itself properly.

Comment: Red rectangle's resolution is 608x390 or 584x366?